# Inserting values into a third table by CROSS JOINing two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to insert values into a `Table_C` by cross joining two tables `Table_A and Table_B`.

```
Table_A contains two attributes ID and item.
Table_B contains two attributes ID and color.
Table_C contains four attributes ID,item,color,quantity.
```

All `IDs` have `AUTO INCREMENT`.

suppose each item can have all `color` and I need to create a relation about it.
How should I write a query for this? How could I reference a relation cross joining `item` and `color`.
What my solution is create an intermediate third table joining these two tables and then use that table to insert values into `Table_C`. But I am pretty sure that there is a better optimized solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query which worked for me.

```
INSERT INTO Table_C (SELECT null, Table_A.item, Table_B.color, null FROM 
Table_A CROSS JOIN Table_B);
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a temp table... You can do:

```
insert into ...
select ... from ...
```

Write the query you'd need to "fill" that temp table you mention, and insert the rows directly into your final table.

Comment: Thanx for your precious reply.